# Fastest Way to Add Character at First, End and Between of each string in List of string

Tags: c#, string, list, c#-4.0, join

This is my list:

```
List<string> elements = new List<string> { "apple", "orange", "peach" };
```

I need a method with this return value:

```
string result = "'apple', 'orange', 'peach'";
```

As you see the result add `"'"` to the first of each string, also at the end of them, then all of them joined with `", "`. So what is your suggestion to do it fast and fluent? also consider performance issues, and maybe this list have been a lot of elements, how about that?

Comment: Why is this needed? Is this some kind of code formating? If so, how a ' containted in a string should be handled?

Comment: @SWeko this is part of Where Clause Generator, like: `Where Name in ('apple', 'orange', 'peach')`

Comment: So what happens when one of the strings is O'Shea ? If these strings are user supplied you are opening the application to SQL Injection.

Comment: @SWeko The user just can use with parameters, but I need to generate some In Filter, do you have any idea about In Filter and pass parameters?

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, take a look at [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#List), is a great article.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Throwing my suggestion in:

```
string result = string.Join(", ", elements.Select(e => "'" + e + "'"));
```

Comment: missing a + in the end `e + "'"));`

Comment: Well on performance basis i will not go with it. Why? Iteration for each element will call select and in the last string.Join itself uses iteration. So if n elements are there there will be n + 1 iteration.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, `Select` is evaluated lazily, and is only called once, before the call to `Join`.  This is close to the most performant method.  Using a `StringBuilder` would be faster, but in a lot more lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
string result = string.Empty;

if (elements.Count > 0) 
    result = "'" + string.Join("', '", elements) + "'"
```

Comment: You shouldn't copy the 2nd version from @Saeed Neamati, your first version is good enough - and I hate ghost edit

Comment: This probably doesn't produce the desired output on an empty list.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is:

```
string result = 
"'" + elements.Aggregate((a, b) => string.Format("{0}', '{1}", a, b)) + "'"
```

BTW, stack exchange has a site called code review. I think that place is more suitable for this question.

Comment: your answer return some additional characters : `''apple', 'orange'', 'peach'`

Comment: Your answer will not be like what OP wanted.

Comment: Wouldn't it actually produce `'''apple'', 'orange'', 'peach'`

Comment: Worse. That all Aggregate method and Lambda variable can be avoided with string.Join(). See my answer.